# Why is rsync recopying a lot of file when I sync to an USB key?

Tags: rsync

When I do an rsync to USB key using -t, it still copy a lot of file.  Why?

Comment: Your question is clear, -t is not expected to have an effect on the number of files copied. Are you referring to files being copied when they already exist on the target ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Microsoft filesystem can only store even values.  Then rsync retransfer any file with an odd value.

You can avoid this by specifying the --modify-window=1 option